# Bootstrap `nav` element is not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, electron, nav

I have a bootstrap `nav` element where I have some icons inside for closing and minimizing. The problem is that these icons are not clickable. I tried to position them outside the `nav` and they become clickable.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="custom-navbar">
        <span class="navbar-brand">Project Title</span>
        <div class="navButtons">
            <a href="#" id="i-close">
                <svg style="pointer-events: none;" class="float-right ml-auto nav-icons" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="20" height="20"
                    fill="none" stroke="currentcolor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2">
                    <path d="M2 30 L30 2 M30 30 L2 2" />
                </svg>
            </a>
            <a id='i-minus'>
                <svg class="nav-icons" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="20"
                    height="20" fill="none" stroke="currentcolor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2">
                    <path d="M2 16 L30 16" />
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

JS

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
window.Bootstrap = require('bootstrap')
$("#i-close").click(() =>{
console.log("clicked!")
alert("working")
})
```

CSS

```
    /* navbar */
  #custom-navbar{
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;

  }

  /* navbar icons */

  .nav-icons{
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    /* border:0.5px solid black; */
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
```

Note that this is an electron app where the window is frame-less.

Any ideas,,

## Edit

I realized that `-webkit-app-region: drag;` will make the whole `nav` not clickable.

Comment: It's not enaugh code to find issue without CSS - there are few versions for alpha, beta etc. But check with inspector what covers the icons and for this element set CSS rule `pointer-events: none` - so every click event will be passed to lower layers.

Comment: @Zydnar I have added the CSS.

Comment: @Zydnar the problem is that I cannot fire click event on the `nav` itself.

Comment: Remove `pointer-events: none` and it works https://jsfiddle.net/ukwbvs1z/

Comment: @Zydnar Please check my edit on the question. The last section titled *edit*

Answer (score 2):

> From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):
>
> pointer-events: none;
>
> **none**: The element is never the target of pointer events; however, pointer events may target its descendant elements if those descendants have pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, pointer events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event capture/bubble phases.

That means you need to remove **pointer-events: none;** from svg i-close:

```js
$("#i-close").on('click', function (e) {
    console.log("clicked!")
    //alert("working")
})
```

```css
#custom-navbar {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;

}

/* navbar icons */

.nav-icons {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    /* border:0.5px solid black; */
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light" id="custom-navbar">
    <span class="navbar-brand">Project Title</span>
    <div class="navButtons">
        <a href="#" id="i-close">
            <svg style="" class="float-right ml-auto nav-icons" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="20" height="20"
                 fill="none" stroke="currentcolor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2">
                <path d="M2 30 L30 2 M30 30 L2 2" />
            </svg>
        </a>
        <a id='i-minus'>
            <svg class="nav-icons" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="20"
                 height="20" fill="none" stroke="currentcolor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                 stroke-width="2">
                <path d="M2 16 L30 16" />
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In same time as my comment :)

Comment: It worked here, but did not work on my editor. What might be the problem?

Comment: Did you remove **pointer-events: none** style? May you post the rendered HTML fragment with css and js? Did you compare the libs I used with yours?

Comment: For the libs, I am getting them from local directory. In the html, I am importing only Bootstrap:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

for the jquery, I am importing it in the js file only. For the `popper `, I did not import it at all.

Comment: The problem with cdn is that electron prefer not to connect to Internet. That is why I am using them locally from node_modules file.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js">`

Here is the popper.js import line. I added it but no effect so far.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js"></script>`

Comment: If I am using this statement `const $ = require('jquery');` then there is no  need to enclose it within DOM ready function

Comment: @gaetanoM I realized the problem. This happening because of `-webkit-app-region: drag;` on the nav. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the edit I have added to the last of the question, the solution was to include:

```
-webkit-app-region:no-drag;
```

in the css file for both buttons.

Thanks for your time and effort.